# Dynamically set iOS Bundle Display Name in Xcode 4 on Build

Tags: ios, xcode

i would like to know wether it's possible to change the bundle display name of an app by for example. changing a preprocessor macro.

This would be helpful if you need different versions of your app, just to differentiate on your iphone's homescreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you **cannot** set the `CFBundleDisplayName` programatically, however if your application is localized you could set different `CFBundleDisplayName` values for each language what are in your localization list.

if you upload a new version to the AppStore, theoretically you **can** change a `CFBundleDisplayName` for each new version. if you are lucky, the Apple won't complain it.

Answer (score 0):

You may not do it *dynamically* (and especially not with macros; which are a compiler feature, not a runtime feature), however, you can localize your application name.  If you wish to change the name of you application, change the value for the info-plist key `LSBundleDisplayName`.